# Service Worker and navigation preload

Tags: service-worker

The UI thread sends a request to the render process to launch SW and in parallel issues a command to the network thread to load data. There is a speed gain if SW still needs to load data rather than take it from the cache. Fine.
And if SW does not need to download data, but we found out about this after its boot-up, then it turns out that we are wasting traffic on unnecessary downloading? Or we can differentiate the process in navigation preload. For example, start loading only part of the data, and the rest at the request of SW? Or SW can cancel an already unnecessary boot if it has not completed by the time its boot-up ends.
How boot-up SW and navigation preload relate to each other in time. Do they most often end at the same time or does one take longer than the other?
And if we managed to quickly make a navigation preload, then how much faster is accessing the cache than streaming data from the browser process to render?

I read the Google documentation and didn't fully understand it